# How to do sane "set-difference" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, set-difference

Demo (I expect result `[3]`):

```
[1,2] - [1,2,3] => []    # Hmm
[1,2,3] - [1,2] => [3]   # I see

a = [1,2].to_set   => #<Set: {1, 2}>
b = [1,2,3].to_set => #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>
a - b              => #<Set: {}>  WTF!
```

And:

```
[1,2,9] - [1,2,3] => [9]  # Hmm. Would like [[9],[3]]
```

How is one to perform a real set difference regardless of order of the inputs?

Ps. As an aside, I need to do this for two 2000-element arrays. Usually, array #1 will have fewer elements than array #2, but this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The [`-` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2D) applied to two arrays `a` and `b` gives the [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement) of `b` in `a` (items that are in `a` but not in `b`).

What you are looking for is the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of two sets (the union of both relative complements between the two). This will do the trick:

```
a = [1, 2, 9]
b = [1, 2, 3]
a - b | b - a          # => [3, 9]
```

If you are operating on [`Set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) objects, you may use the overloaded [`^` operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-5E):

```
c = Set[1, 2, 9]
d = Set[1, 2, 3]
c ^ d                  # => #<Set: {3, 9}>
```

For extra fun, you could also find the relative complement of the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) in the [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29) of the two sets:

```
( a | b ) - ( a & b )  # => #<Set: {3, 9}>
```

Comment: +1, nice answer. I added Array#^ to my [extension library](http://rubydoc.info/gems/shenanigans/1.0.4/Array#%5E-instance_method), it's not always necessary to go through sets.

Comment: I assume sets are faster but would be good to know how `-` for arrays and `^` for sets compare performance wise.